# Writing a program using Switch Case Statement (with the use of letters ABCD not int)

Tags: java, string, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I have my code written in if/else Statement and it is working but I have a problem in writing it using switch statement as it appears that there are problems in my variables and symbols.

Can you please spot what is wrong and help me correct it?

My source code below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class CourseCodeSWITCH {

    public static void main(String[] a) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        String code;
        System.out.print("Enter Course Code: ");
        code = in.nextLine();
        switch (code) {
            case A: code = "Accounting";
                    break;
            case B: code = "Banking and Finance";
                    break;
            case C: code = "Computer Science";
                    break;
            case D: code = "Dentistry";
                    break;
            case E: code = "Engineering";
                    break;
        default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Course Code");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding, `"... there are problems in my variables and symbols"` -- Please clarify what you mean by "problems..."? Error messages? Does it not compile? Please help us out.

Comment: First A, B, C, etc, should apparently be variables, but they are not defined anywhere. I guess you wanted to use strings "A", "B", etc.

Comment: @Hovercraft it does not compile and the error message is this -   symbol:   variable E
  location: class CourseCodeSWITCH
5 errors

Comment: @Axl And if he sticks to using only one letter 'A' will do too, this will even work with Java 6

Comment: @Axl yes, I would want to use string because if I put Case 1, the error "int cannot be converted to string" appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Java 7/8` you can define the `String` to compare `code` to. In earlier versions you may want to use a `char` or `enum`.

```
public static void main(String[] a) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    String code;
    System.out.print("Enter Course Code: ");
    code = in.nextLine();
    switch (code) {
        case "A": 
             code = "Accounting";
                break;
        case "B": 
             code = "Banking and Finance";
                break;
        case "C": 
             code = "Computer Science";
                break;
        case "D": 
             code = "Dentistry";
                break;
        case "E": 
             code = "Engineering";
                break;
    default:
            System.out.println("Invalid Course Code");
            break;
    }
```

Additionally here is an [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html) from Oracle.

Comment: @LanguidSquid I seeeee... my problem was, I have not enclosed the letters with "" as in letter E to be "E". That was the problem. Thank you, it's now working... Million thanks! :)

Comment: @Marged jcreator pro ver 4.50

Answer (score 3):

You're using A, B, C, as labels, but that's not how a switch statement works. Let's take a look at just one statement:

```
switch (code) {
    case A: code = "Accounting";
        break;
```

You're switching on `code`... this means you're going to be examining the contents of the `code` variable.

Next, you declare a case. In the case above, you're effectively saying

```
if (code == A)
    code = "Accounting";
    break;
```

Now, there's a couple things wrong with that. First of all, `A` is not defined anywhere, so you're immediately going to run into compile-time errors. You probably wanted to use a String value (`"A"`) instead. Second, you're just reassigning `code` instead of outputting like you did in your original if-statement.

You probably want a switch that looks closer to the following:

```
switch(code) {
    case "A":
        System.out.println("Assignment");
        break;
    case "B":
        System.out.println("Banking and Finance");
        break;
    // and so forth
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. my teacher actually haven't made himself clear in explaining everything.. it's like, I only got less than 15% in our lecture for this subject and yet he gave us sooooo many HW, and so I am left with learning more thru the net and you guys.. Sorry I cannot check yours since the other one came in first and so what I can do is to upvote yours though I have to say that you have explained it so good.. Thank you!